# NOSQL vs XML document storage

Tags: xml, nosql

When to choose NoSQL and when to choose XML ?

Update: I want to know when one can use NoSQL exclusively, XML exclusively or both. I want real examples not generalities.

Comment: Are you trying to store Word documents?

Comment: Since when were nosql and XML mutually exclusive?

Comment: Did I say it is always exclusive ? I want to know when one can use NoSQL exclusively, XML exclusively or both. I want real examples not generalities.

Comment: What about a relational database, why is that not a viable choice?

Comment: I have nothing against Relational DB and I have no problem about them it's just that NoSQL is more new so my question :)

Answer (score 2):

I want to get some goods from my shop to a customer. Do I walk, or should I use a SatNav?

Your question seems rather confused. NoSQL and XML aren't obviously clear alternatives - you could store your documents using XML in a NoSQL type database. Please clarify what you already have, what you want to do and what your constraints are.

Comment: I have no clear needs, I'm just preparing for real world projects I would meet in some future which can be very diverse what I know is that they will need to support hundred of millions of hits per year.

Comment: One hundred million hits a year corresponds to roughly 3 per second. How about just using the file system?

Comment: because I will probably need to extract info in these documents (more like a spreadsheet-like document) depending on some keys.